# Docker Toolboxのインストールがうまくいきません (windows10)

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, docker-toolbox

windows10 home editionで
DockerToolbox-18.03.0-ceをインストールして、Docker Quickstart Terminal を管理者として実行したら、以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

パソコンの実行環境
エディション  Windows 10 Home
バージョン   20H2
インストール日 ‎2021/‎08/‎08
OS ビルド  19042.662
エクスペリエンス    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

デバイス名   LAPTOP-ATRMJIKB
プロセッサ   AMD Ryzen 5 Microsoft Surface (R) Edition   2.20 GHz
実装 RAM  8.00 GB (7.45 GB 使用可能)
システムの種類 64 ビット オペレーティング システム、x64 ベース プロセッサ
ペンとタッチ  10 タッチ ポイントでのペンとタッチのサポート

どのようにすればクジラのような絵が出てうまくいくのでしょうか。

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\setsu\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\setsu\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to load R0 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VMMR0.r0: SUP_IOCTL_LDR_OPEN failed (VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:00.408052 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_LDR_GENERAL_FAILURE, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...
```

アンインストールしてもう一度再インストールすると以下の表示になりました。

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to create a network adapter. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: E_FAIL
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Querying NetCfgInstanceId failed (0x00000002)
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default)
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Docker Toolboxは現在非推奨らしい [Windows/MacでDockerを使う3つの方法](https://www.codelab.jp/blog/?p=2845) のと、最新版は [v19.03.1](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox) なので何か特別な理由が無い限り諦めた方が良いのでは？

Comment: VirtualBoxを使用したいのでDocker Toolboxでないとダメみたいです。
最新版をインストールをしたほうがいいのでしょうか?

Comment: まだ質問を出したばかりなので、エラーメッセージから対策を回答してくれる人が居るかもしれませんので待ってみてください。ただ、特に理由が無い限り最新版を使った方が良いと思われます。

Comment: [`v18.03.0-ce`](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/releases/tag/v18.03.0-ce) の VirtualBoxのバージョンは `5.2.8` 、加えて[README](https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/blob/master/README.md) の記述を見るに、"仮想化技術(VT-x)を**有効化**する" かつ "Hyper-Vを**無効化**する" 必要がありそうです。(※ Virtual Boxは必ずしもこのバージョンを用いる必要は無いようですが、2019年で開発が終了しているため、現在のVirtual Box バージョン6系統では動作する確証は何も無いでしょう)/ [エラーコードで検索する](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69864455/4506703)と特定のVirtualBoxバージョンに起因する問題の可能性もありそうですので、もう少し詳細な実行環境の情報を記載したほうが良いかも知れません。

Comment: どのVirtualBoxのバージョンをインストールすればいいのでしょうか。